# error SQL Error [923] [42000]: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
   SUM(id_fatura) as 'Val1',
   SUM(id_linha_fatura) as 'Val2',
   SUM(id_contrato) as 'Val3',
   SUM(id_servico) as 'Val4',
   SUM(valor) as 'Val5',
   (SUM(Val1) + SUM(Val2) + SUM(Val3) + SUM(val4) + SUM(val5)) as 'soma_faturas'
FROM DETALHE_FATURA;
```

Appear a error

> SQL Error [923] [42000]: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where
>   expected.

can anyone explain me why is appearing me this error

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? (The error message looks more like Oracle.)

Comment: no, i´m using oracle

Comment: Thank Ian, who has already replaced the tag.

Comment: 1) Quoted aliases, remove qoutes 2) using aliases instead of fieldnames `SUM(Val1) + SUM(Val2)+...` instead of `SUM(id_fatura)+SUM(id_linha_fatura)+...`.

Comment: And again - the question closed with the reference to the answers which do NOT solve.

Comment: i tried a different way, SELECT ((id_fatura) + (id_linha_fatura) + (id_contrato) + (id_servico) + (valor)) AS total_fatura
FROM DETALHE_FATURA
GROUP BY id_fatura, ID_LINHA_FATURA, ID_CONTRATO, ID_SERVICO ,VALOR;                                      and it worked

Comment: I do not recommend. In such case server cannot re-use already calculated separate sums and must additionally summarize separate fields of each record then sum them into one. Excess work without any profit except a lot of economized bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Try fixing that:

```
SELECT SUM(id_fatura) as Val1,
       SUM(id_linha_fatura) as Val2,
       SUM(id_contrato) as Val3,
       SUM(id_servico) as Val4,
       SUM(valor) as Val5,
       (SUM(id_fatura) + SUM(id_linha_fatura) + SUM(id_contrato) + SUM(id_servico) + SUM(valor)) as soma_faturas
FROM DETALHE_FATURA;
```

Although some databases do allow single quotes for column aliases, they are a bad idea, because they confuse the *name* of a column with the *values* in the columns.  Identifiers and values are different things.

In addition, you need to repeat the expressions for the `soma_faturas` column.  You cannot refer to the aliases (which is apparently what you want to do).  You could use a CTE or subquery if the expressions are complicated.

Comment: when i do that , appear another error!!   SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "VAL4": invalid identifier